# Mysql error 1261 (doesn't contain data for all columns) on last row with no empty values

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I'm doing a lad data infile in MySQL through MySQL Workbench. I'm pretty new to SQL in general, so this may be a simple fix, but I can't get it to work. It is throwing a a 1261 Error (doesn't contain data for all columns) on the last row, but the last row (like the rest of the CSV) doesn't have any blank or null values.

I've looked around for help and read the manual, but everything I've seen has been about dealing with null values.

I exported the CSV from Excel, to the extent that maters.

The code I'm using to import is (I've changed the field, file, and table names to be more generic):

```
load data infile '/temp/filename.csv'
into table table1
fields terminated by ","
lines terminated by '\r'
ignore 1 lines
(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,col6,col7,Col8,Col9);
```

The first two columns are varchar and char, respectively with the remaining columns all formatted as double.

Here's the last few lines of the csv file:

```
364,6001.009JR,43.96,0,0,0,0,0,0
364,6001.900FM,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
364,6001.900JR,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

The only thing I can think of is that I'm supposed to have some signal after the last line to indicate that the file is finished, but I haven't found anything to indicate what that would be.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When I've had similar errors, it's because there were unexpected newlines inside my data (a newline in one row would look like two too-short rows, upon import).